# Ejabberd clustering chat not working

Tags: ejabberd

I am trying ejabberd clustering i studied lot of material for ejabberd clustering finally i got  ejabberd clustering. If i do this  in terminal mnesia:info()  two erlang running node. When chat with tkabber client i could not get any log for my ejabberd log file is this working.

Answer (score 0):

You can check http://guntanis.tumblr.com/post/63791220016/ejabberd-2-1-cluster-on-aws-ubuntu
It has step by step instructions of clustering once you have ejabberd installed.

Comment: i got like this running db nodes   = [‘ejabberd@server-02’,’ejabberd@server-01’] but if i stop server01 mean server02 did not get any chat messages.

Comment: did you copy all the mnesia tables?

Comment: yes i copied all the mnesia table following command mnesia:change_table_copy_type(schema, node(), disc_copies).
mnesia:add_table_copy(config, node(), disc_copies). etc ... is any other steps i missed in clustering both nodes are run but why cant i communicate with slave node