# How to do ejabberd cluster load balancing the right way?

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I have set up one cluster (node1 and node2) by following steps [here](https://github.com/chadillac/ejabberd-easy_cluster/) in the same domain(talk.example.com).

I have tested the cluster with two clients, which are connected to different nodes' ip(not the domain talk.example.com). But I want to know how to distribute clients in the cluster if I want to the clients to connect to the DNS record(talk.example.com), not the IPs for the nodes in the cluster?

DNS round robin？I don't know if this work for the same client if different ip is return for the same clients, for XMPP protocol is stateful。Or Linux Virtual Server? I have never try this before.

I have read [Service Load-Balancing](http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#htoc93), but which node will be the frontend(the one that client will connect to)?

Comment: Or there is no master node for router, local router, sessoin manager or s2s Manager will always find the right one(and do the load balancing)?

Comment: May be this is the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444022/ejabberd-clustering-chat-not-working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use either DNS balancing or load balancer such as haproxy or even both.

DNS is actually the simplest one but you need to remember that it is the SRV record _xmpp-client._tcp.{your domain} has to be balanced, not your real domain.

Comment: Haproxy acts as a gateway to the XMPP servers. (correct me if I'm wrong), the connections being persistent, isnt it a overhead for haproxy to maintain the live connections? I mean soon HA will be overloaded due to maintaining the connections with the XMPP. Will the communication be like Client -> HA -> XMPP and vice-versa (XMPP-> HA -> Client).? Or does it `reroute` the connection to one of the XMPP, freeing itself from making a persistent connection ?

Comment: Nginx also can be used for load balancing,

Comment: Are you sure you can proxy plain TCP connections using NGINX?